# Adjusting MULTIROW and MULTICOL in one table

Tags: multirow

For the following code, I am unable to adjust the `Replicates` word in the third row across all the above rows via `\multirow` command.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
     & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{$N_0$} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{$N_1$} \\\hline
     & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$P_0$} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$P_1$} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$P_0$} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$P_1$}\\\hline
Replicates  & $K_0$ & $K_1$ & $K_0$ & $K_1$ & $K_0$ & $K_1$ & $K_0$ & $K_1$ \\\hline
    1   & 9  & 7  & 18 & 10 & 24 & 20 & 7  & 9  \\%\hline
    2   & 14 & 21 & 29 & 15 & 18 & 22 & 12 & 13 \\
    3   & 13 & 14 & 21 & 13 & 20 & 24 & 9  & 14 \\
    4   & 15 & 18 & 32 & 14 & 12 & 26 & 16 & 15 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
     & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{$N_0$} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{$N_1$} \\ \cline{2-9} % <-- changed
     & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$P_0$} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$P_1$} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$P_0$} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$P_1$}\\\cline{2-9} % <-- changed
\multirow{-3}*{Replicates} % <---- see here
        & $K_0$ & $K_1$ & $K_0$ & $K_1$ & $K_0$ & $K_1$ & $K_0$ & $K_1$ \\\hline
    1   & 9  & 7  & 18 & 10 & 24 & 20 & 7  & 9  \\%\hline
    2   & 14 & 21 & 29 & 15 & 18 & 22 & 12 & 13 \\
    3   & 13 & 14 & 21 & 13 & 20 & 24 & 9  & 14 \\
    4   & 15 & 18 & 32 & 14 & 12 & 26 & 16 & 15 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```